# Starting AngularJS, NodeJS, Express, and Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, express

so I found this site [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/angularjs-nodejs-and-firebase-startup-web-developers-toolkit/) that starts with a introduction how to make an web app using angularjs as front end, node and express as backend and firebase to store data.

The thing is I have no idea how or where to start? I tried searching for quite a while but it only leads me to angularjs and firebase directly.

My questions are:

1. Is it necessary to have nodejs and express?
2. Do you guys know any tutorials that guides step by step using those
   four? I would like to see a simple crud and an authentication app that uses those four mentioned in the title.
3. Do I need to install anything? recommended IDE for those?

I have played with angularjs for quite some time now. I had a project before that uses angularjs spring and mysql so angularjs is quite familiar for me but the other three are complete strangers.

I saw a command like this `$ npm install express-generator -g` so how do I install it? using command prompt?

Keywords, urls, or any resources will be appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend  a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

1)You don't have to use NodeJS&Express you can use whatever you know as backend language but if you know Javascript I'd recommend you to start with NodeJS(with Express or Koa which are nodejs web application frameworks allow you to use like post-get processes etc)

2)People who are using Nodejs with Angular usually using MEAN(MongoDB,Express, Angular,NodeJS), and I'd definitely recommend you to follow this videos [Maximilian Schwarzmüller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tRLveSyNz8)'s channel he is really good with teaching.

3)It depends on you, I'm using VSCode now ,others maybe Webstorm.Deciding IDE is up to you

To be able to install npm packages you need to download NodeJS from [NodeJS website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) then  automatically  npm installed on your computer and you can install any package like express-generator(which creates an application skeleton.)

Keep researching,have a good day.